# Why union of unit type intersections results in never type?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-level-computation

Could you please explain why the following type expression results in `never` type? And why the second expression evaluates to `"c"`?

```
type t1 = ("a" & "b") | ("c" & "d"); // never
type t2 = ("a" & "b") | "c"; // "c"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `never` is the type that contains zero values.

`t1`: There is no value that is both `"a"` and `"b"`, so the type `"a" & "b"` is the same as `never`. Same for `c` and `d`.

`t2`: If a value is either `"c"` or a value that is both `"a"` and `"b"`, then it must be `"c"`.

You can think of `never` as the identity operand for `|`, the same way that `0` is the identity operand for addition: `3 + 0` is `3`

Comment: I was wondering why just a simple `"a" & "b"` doesn't reduce to `never`, in fact it remains `"a" & "b"` and when you assign string literal `"a"` to a variable of such type you get an error message `"Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'"`

Comment: It's an artifact of how TS internally represents combinations of intersections and unions. TS will "simplify" types when it detects it's necessary (this will result in impossible intersections becoming 'never'), but a bare intersection doesn't need simplification so its display remains as-is.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification, good luck on 3.7 release!)

Answer (score 1):

There is no value that can satisfy the type signature `"a" & "b"` so in fact, that type can be reduced to `never`. However, I will grant that this is slightly confusing because, for some reason, the type system doesn't try to reduce the type until you add the union.

```
type t1 = "a" & "b";                 // "a" & "b"
type t2 = ("a" & "b") | ("a" & "b"); // never
```

For your second question, because there is no value that can satisfy `"a" & "b"`, the *only* value that can satisfy `("a" & "b") | "c"` is just `"c"`.