# Why type intersections results in never type?

Tags: typescript

Could you please explain why the following type expression results in never type? And why the second expression evaluates to "{ d: false, e: never }"?

```js
// 1、
// never
type DataTypeNever = {
  d: true;
  e: number;
} & {
  d: false;
  e: number;
}

let data: DataTypeNever = (() => {
  throw new Error
})()
```

```js
// 2、
// { d: false, e: never }
type DataType = {
  d: false;
  e: number;
} & {
  d: false;
  e: string;
}

let data: DataType = {
    d: false,
    e: (() => {
      throw new Error
    })()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why union of unit type intersections results in never type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930332/why-union-of-unit-type-intersections-results-in-never-type)

Comment: How could something be true and false at the same time?

Comment: Why can't the result be `{ d: never, e: number }`? @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: I think it's a bug in TypeScript.
`const a: number & null = null; // Error (never type)
const a: boolean & null = null; // Ok (null type)`

Comment: I tried the two examples you sent. The type inference result is never type. @Honsemiro Take a look at this link
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhmArgWwEYFMBOMBkyKANsTALxGkDcMA9HTACoCeADljAOSqlcwBLCMhCw4ECAIDmYOBmKcoIGFHaceWAG64uAOgAUAJgDMhwwEoAUKEiwMSDCBAK4YAlTKVexWg2Zrub34hETEJaVl5RWVVDkCtHQMTM3MgA

Comment: For 1, it's `never` because `true` and `false` are unit types and thus can act as *discriminant* of [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and [intersections are reduced by discriminant properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties).  For 2 it's `{d: false, e: never}` because `string` and `number` are not unit types and cannot act as discriminants, so the intersection isn't reduced. Instead the individual properties are intersected.

Comment: Does that make sense and answer your question? If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Set strictNullChecks to false in tsconfig.json and try again @Jason.

Comment: Thank you very much. According to your comments, I found the PR of typescript on this issue @jcalz https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36696) of typescript about this issue

Such is the main content:

We have long speculated that intersections of object types with discriminant properties of disjoint types should be eqivalent to `never` (the empty type), since objects of such types are not possible to construct. This PR finally implements that feature.

In addition to the intersection reduction implemented in [#31838](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31838), an intersection `T1 & T2 & ... & Tn` is equivalent to `never` when

- two or more of the `Tx` types have properties with the same name, and
- in at least one group of properties with the same name, some property has a literal type and no property has type `never`, and
- the intersection of the types of the properties in such a group is `never`.

An example:

```js
type A = { kind: 'a', foo: string };
type B = { kind: 'b', foo: string };
type C = { kind: number, foo: string };
type D = { kind: never, foo: string };
type E = { kind: 'a', foo: number };

type AB = A & B;  // never
type BC = B & C;  // never
type AD = A & D;  // { kind: never, foo: string }
type AE = A & E;  // { kind: never, foo: never }
```